# Laravel 5.1 given ReflectionException in Container.php line 737

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am adding html helper and facing this bellow problem. There is no where i found solution.

Add in composer.json

```
"illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

and run composer update

Open your config/app.php

add under 'providers'

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

add under 'aliases'

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Here Controller File

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class AdminAuthController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('admin-pages.login');
        }

        public function home()
        {
            return view('admin-pages.home');
        }
    }
```

Here Composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Here I am attach Output file[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the controller method you are calling, at least the part where you're trying to return the view?

Comment: @watcher : thank you for response. yes i have update code with controller.

Comment: The error message is saying that somewhere you're trying to use the application to construct a class `view` which doesn't exist (a `View` facade does, but it has a capital 'V'). I can't see where that error is coming from with what you've provided, but that's what you need to find

Comment: try `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

you can pick your route file? I guess that the problem is there... OR try with the facades use View; and call of this way:

```
return View::make('admin-pages.login');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same problem by following the 2 steps bellow :

1. Put "league/oauth2-server": "4.1.*" on the require section of your composer.json file.
2. run 'composer update' command on terminal.

You can try also.